# 2 SQL Server Inner Joins in Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, join

this maybe a simple issue to fix so sorry.

I have a SQL select statement and I have 2 columns, both are Foreign Keys to the same table. Here's an example:

> ProductID = 5 | Seller(UserID) = 3 | Buyer(UserID) = 2

I want the select statement to return

> Product = 5 | Seller(UserID) = Gary Jones | Buyer(UserID) = John Smith

```
Select Product.ID
       User.ID as Seller
       User.ID as Buyer
From   Orders
Inner Join Product on Product.ID = Orders.ProductID
Inner Join User on User.ID = Orders.UserID --(For both buyer and seller)
```

It is possible that the buyers is not a user so should be left null if there is no user:

> Product = 5 | Seller(UserID) = Gary Jones | Buyer(UserID) = Null

Comment: Change your second `Inner Join` to a `Left Join`

Comment: 2 changes...left join to the tables to return nulls (inner will drop the record) and you will need two joins two user, one for buyer and one for seller (unless they are always the same person?).   is there a buyer ID seperate from seller ID in your orders table?

Comment: @Twelfth they are separate fields in the same table that both link to the same field in the users table. How do I do 2 joins?

Comment: Yes...both answers below seem to address that.  You can join to the same table pretty much as many time as you want (well, up to the logical max that these engines support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a left join to get the rows where buyers are not users and also to join the users table twice:

```
Select Product.ID
       u1.ID as Seller -- this should maybe be u1.name and not id?
       u2.ID as Buyer
From   Orders
Inner Join Product on Product.ID = Orders.ProductID
Inner Join User u1 on u1.ID = Orders.SellerID --(For seller)
Left Join User u2 on u2.ID = Orders.BuyerID --(For buyer )
```

I assume your Orders table store Buyer and Seller with IDs, it's those that you should join the User tables with. In the example query I used BuyerID  and SellerID, you have to change that to reflect the correct names.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have buyer and seller id columns on your order table and they are foreign keys to the User table - I named them BuyerID and SellerID respectively. I made some assumptions on other column names too.

```
SELECT 
    p.ID,
    P.ProductName,
    u1.Name as Seller,
    u2.Name as Buyer
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Product p ON p.ID = o.ProductID
LEFT JOIN User u1 ON u1.ID = o.SellerID
LEFT JOIN User u2 ON u2.ID = o.BuyerID
```

Comment: @user3279193 No problem, glad to be of help.